# Android emulator not running with my React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, sdk

Trying to run my React Native app in Android emulator but it keeps throwing error:
"**Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error spawnSync ./gradlew EACCES. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.**"

Tried react-native run-android, npm start, react-native start... nothing worked!!!

[image]

[image]

Am I missing out something here?? struggling with this since morning. Please help....

**Update:**
Ran "adb devices" in terminal. Still its not working :/ Same error!!!

[image]

Comment: Import the project in Android Studio, let gradle configure all dependencies and start the app again using react-native run-android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the permission on `android/gradew`. It should be 755 and not 644.

Run the following command inside your app root folder:

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

The run: `react-native run-android`. If you are on Windows, make sure to run `react-native run-android` in CMD as administrator.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT for the new problem in the comments:**

The following are a few ways you can try to fix the error you mentioned in the comments:

1) Go to FILE -> sync project with gradle files.

If no.1 doesn't work for you. Try no.2

2) Go to `.gradle\caches\2.0\scripts\build_7l4t45nbnsvdcl79ol8u0beli4\ProjectScript` and remove the cache.properties.lock file. If you are on windows try this as: `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\<gradle version such as 2.4 or something else>\scripts>del /S *.lock`

Hope this solves your problem :)

**EDIT 2:**

You can downgrade from your Java 13 to Java 8. It may solve your problems. However, if you are unwilling to downgrade go to `build.gradle` and do the following:

```
compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = /path_to_javac
```

If you do the following above instead of downgrading you will set a concrete path which will hinder your project if you are sharing it with other developers.

This was the best I could come up with from simulating the same problem on one of my test projects in my computer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Now its throwing error       "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not open settings remapped class cache for 76mds5z5o9jvw4bf22hb4vayu (/Users/raksha/.gradle/caches/5.1.1/scripts-remapped/settings_dxh59uz6potz1i95k939u6umk/76mds5z5o9jvw4bf22hb4vayu/settings13bba240a07c562d578336deed5b2fbf).
> Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/raksha/update/notif-center-app/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/raksha/.gradle/caches/5.1.1/scripts/76mds5z5o9jvw4bf22hb4vayu/settings/settings13bba240a07c562d578336deed5b2fbf)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahir. I tried this. Deleted the lock file. But It still throws the same damn error "Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/raksha/update/notif-center-app/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/raksha/.gradle/caches/5.1.1/scripts/76mds5z5o9jvw4bf22hb4vayu/settings/settings13bba240a07c562d578336deed5b2fbf)." "error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug."

Comment: @RakshaHegde what java version are you using?

Comment: openjdk version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @RakshaHegde check the edit 2 if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you actually have a device connected by typing this in terminal

```
adb devices
```

If there is no device detected.

Try typing this in terminal

```
adb kill-server
adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
adb devices
```

If it looks like this

[image: devices ready]

Then you have no problem with Android devices.
Try running the app again with

```
react-native run-android
```

If it's not working, try

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

Comment: check my updated question please. still did not work. I can see my emulator in the list of devices. But when I run "react-native run-android" it shows the same old error "Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment". Any other way??

Answer (score 0):

please add you skds path in windows or mac path environment

[image]